# Emerald on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: gtk, emerald

Is anyone else having issues installing emerald on Ubuntu 15.10? Added a few repositories but having trouble finding the packages?

Does anyone have any pointers for this?

Comment: It's possible it hasn't been updated to 15.10 yet. You can try changing the source to be for 15.04, but it probably won't work.

Comment: Good shout, I'll give it a try when I get home from work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install it on 15.10 using the webupd8 vivid packages.

If you go here http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/webupd8?dist=vivid you can grab the libemeraldengine0 and emerald deb packages and sudo dpkg -i them.

Works well so far!

Comment: That answer deserves +1.

Answer (score -1):

To install Emerald in Ubuntu 15.10, copy + paste this into Termial and press Enter:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emerald/libemeraldengine0_0.9.5-0~webupd8~vivid_i386.deb && wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/e/emerald/emerald_0.9.5-0~webupd8~vivid_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./emerald_0.9.5-0~webupd8~vivid_i386.deb ./libemeraldengine0_0.9.5-0~webupd8~vivid_i386.deb && rm ./libemeraldengine0_0.9.5-0~webupd8~vivid_i386.deb ./emerald_0.9.5-0~webupd8~vivid_i386.deb
```